# How to subtract a number from a counter and avoid "Package pgf Error: No shape named... is known"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The MWE...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \l [count=\i from 0] in {{Text 1}, {Text 2}, {Text 3}} {
      \ifnum\i<2
        \node [align=center, above] at (2*\i, 1.1) {\l};
      \else
        \node [align=center, above] at (3*(\i-1), 1.1) {\l};
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

... leads to the error `Package pgf Error: No shape named 3*(2-1 is known`. How can one subtract a number from a counter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the parentheses. They confuse the parser. Hide them:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \l [count=\i from 0] in {{Text 1}, {Text 2}, {Text 3}} {
      \ifnum\i<2
        \node [align=center, above] at (2*\i, 1.1) {\l};
      \else
        \node [align=center, above] at ({3*(\i-1)}, 1.1) {\l};
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ... and I had tried to put the curly braces around `\i` and `\i-1` but not the whole term. Excellent, thanks a lot for helping, Ulrike.